# Convert Azure group to mail-enabled security group

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, office365

Is there a way to convert a Security or Microsoft 365 group to a Mail-enabled security group?

I tried to perform such a function, but it did not bring the proper result

```
Set-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $ObjectId -SecurityEnabled $true
```

Comment: You cannot convert the group type from Azure group to mail-enabled security group as mentioned in this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/how-to-manage-groups#to-edit-your-group-settings)